# RPI Serial Communication through USB

Tags: usb, linux, serial, pi-zero, uart

I am trying to set up serial communication between my Raspberry Pi Zero W and my PSoC. I want to do this through a normal microUSB to USB 2.0 converter cable, which looks somewhat like this picture:
[image]

This means I am going to be using the microUSB port on my RPI and NOT the GPIO pins. Furthermore, I am also only going to be using the USB port on my PSoC and not any of the pins either.
My question is: How do I find the `/dev/tty` driver on Linux for this specific USB port? Keep in mind, that I already have my left USB port connected to my PC. Therefore, I am asking about the USB port to the right.

Also, how do I find out whether it is enabled or not, and how do I configure the baud rate and set it to TX.

Comment: The PiZeroW has only **one** USB port!

Comment: @Milliways
Why do I see two microUSBs then? https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-am5zt8xfow/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/1119/2803/api60n3ij__57512.1548550149.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on

Comment: One is a power port (quite clearly labelled as such in your link) - try reading the [Foundation Specs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/)

Comment: @Milliways
Oh, well. I see that now. And there is absolutely no way that I can turn that into a USB port?